# How to consume rules defined in the KIE-Workbench from the another java web application?

Tags: jboss, drools, jbpm, drools-guvnor, kie

I don't have previous work experience for the drools and everything. But due to my project requirement I need to use drools KIE-wirkbench rules integration. I know how to define rules inside the KIE but I don't know how to consume those rules inside the other application. Please suggest me some ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/krisv/jbpm-evaluation-examples/blob/master/kjar-from-guvnor/src/main/java/org/jbpm/evaluation/EvaluationExampleKJarFromGuvnor.java

While it's a jBPM example, the same code would work for Drools as well.